# Problem evaluating a complicated integral

Tags: numerical-integration, summation, astronomy

Apologies for stating my problem poorly in the first instance, thank you for the help in narrowing down the issue.

**Problem**

For those interested, it's for the exact unbiased inverse of the generalized [Anscombe Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform), as given in this paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2012.2202675.

I'm trying to integrate, for a given value of $y$ and $\sigma$, the function

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{\sigma}\left ( z \right ) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{y^{k}\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{k!\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^{2}}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left ( z-k \right )^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}} \right ) \mathrm{d}z
$$

where

$$
f_{\sigma}\left ( z \right ) =  \left\{\begin{matrix}
2\sqrt{z+\frac{3}{8}+\sigma^{2}}, & z > -\frac{3}{8}-\sigma^{2}\\ 
0, & z \leq -\frac{3}{8}-\sigma^{2}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

which gives the equation in the reference below:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 2\sqrt{z+\frac{3}{8}+\sigma ^{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{y^{k}\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{k!\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^{2}}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left ( z-k \right )^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}} \right ) \mathrm{d}z
$$

In the reference, the values of the above function are tabulated, presumably in Matlab, for $\sigma \in \left \{ 0.01,...,50 \right \}$ and $y \in \left \{0,...,200 \right \}$. The authors have made this table available for [download](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/invansc/), but I want to do it myself.

However, I can't get it to work - Mathematica won't evaluate it:

```
func[z_, y_, sig_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2 Sqrt[z + 3/8 + sig^2],z > -3/8 - sig^2}},0.]*
  Sum[((y^k )* Exp[-y])/(k! * Sqrt[2 \[Pi] sig^2]) * 
    Exp[-((z - k)^2) / (2 sig^2)], {k, 0, Infinity}]
NIntegrate[func[z, 5, 2], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Have I made a mistake somewhere? Or misunderstood the integral/problem as given?

**Update**

A suggestion is to replace the infinite sum with an upper limit of ~50 as it converges quickly. This does allow Mathematica to now evaluate the integral.

Comment: Is this supposed to be real?

Comment: Looking at the table of values provided by the authors of the reference, yes.

Comment: But what happens for values $z<-(3/8+\sigma^2)$?

Comment: Anyway try `uplim = 50;
arg = N[2 Sqrt[z + 3/8 + 2^2]*
    Total@Table[((5^k)*Exp[-5])/(k!*Sqrt[2 \[Pi] 2^2])*
       Exp[-((z - k)^2)/(2 2^2)], {k, 0, uplim}]
   ];
Plot[arg, {z, -10, 20}]
NIntegrate[arg, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`. This constructs the series by hand.

Comment: Ah yes, good point, sorry! For $z \leq -(\frac{3}{8} + \sigma^{2})$ the value you specify, the forward Anscombe transform is defined as zero

Comment: Then add this information to the question! OK, so this is answered then?

Comment: Well-spotted, hadn't realised I'd missed it - will add now.

Comment: Sigh, it's been a long day - thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your edit makes things still worse, and is not compatible with the limits of the integral. I suggest you reconsider the statement of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alexei - have rewritten it as best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be real, since `z`under the radical goes to minus infinity. Anyway, if you only need a numerical table, why do not you do something like this:

```
    f[y_, sig_, n_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2 Sqrt[z + 3/8 + sig^2]*
   Sum[((y^k)*Exp[-y])/(k!*Sqrt[2 \[Pi] sig^2])*
     Exp[-((z - k)^2)/(2 sig^2)], {k, 0, 
     n}], {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Here `n`is the number of terms in the sum. It converges rather fast. To check it let us do the following:

```
 f[5, 2, #] & /@ {10, 100, 1000}

(*   {5.92884 + 0.000418281 I, 6.03812 + 0.000418544 I, 
 6.03812 + 0.000418544 I}   *)
```

The result is complex, which is to be expected, and not related to the number of terms in the sum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - as @acl has pointed out I managed to miss of a somewhat crucial piece of information regarding $z$ (now added), for which I must apologise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that if the integrand is complex we should take it to be zero, you can do this:

```
uplim = 50;
arg = If[Im@# > 0, 0, #] &@
   N[2 Sqrt[z + 3/8 + 2^2]*
     Total@Table[((5^k)*Exp[-5])/(k!*Sqrt[2 \[Pi] 2^2])*
        Exp[-((z - k)^2)/(2 2^2)], {k, 0, uplim}]
    ];
Plot[arg, {z, -10, 20}]
NIntegrate[arg, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

This constructs the series by hand, up to some upper value (I worked out that 50 is enough by looking at the plot